# Google Authentication and Facebook authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I want to integrate google authentication to my website. I am using reactJS as front end and nodeJS as backend and mongoose for Database... Please help me to integrate google authentication and Facebook authentication to my website.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Google authentication and facebook authentication can be integrated using passport js and express-sessions (in order to store "session state") in your node js backend. I recommend checking out the passport js docs as well as any tutorials that you can find on the topic. Passport provides easy to use middleware functions that will share cookies with your client application for authentication.

> Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js. Extremely flexible and modular, Passport can be unobtrusively dropped in to any Express-based web application. A comprehensive set of strategies support authentication using a username and password, Facebook, Twitter, and more.

http://passportjs.org/
https://github.com/expressjs/session